# How to use a reusable component inside another component with fields with matching ids

Tags: angular, components

I have 2 components. Main component and popUpComponent. I am using popUpComponent inside the main component. 
Main component has a form in it and inside this form there is a checkbox with the **id="active"**.

```
<input class="switch-input" [disabled]="pageStatus==4" [ngModel]="role.active"  name="active" id="active" type="checkbox" >
```

In my pop up component (which is intended to be reusable). I also have another checkbox again with the **id of "active"**

```
<input class="switch-input" [ngModel]="popup.active"  name="active" id="active" type="checkbox" >
```

And i am getting the following error from chrome.

```
Found 2 elements with non-unique id #active:
```

**My question is, how can i create a reusable component when i can not know if the main components will include a field id or not ? is there any workaround for this ?**

Comment: Well, choose an ID that is unique (popup-component-active), or just remove the ID.

Comment: Oh i see, so there is no automatic angular namespace or anything. I have to do it manually and hope it doesn't conflict. Thanks @JBNizet